# device not detected when "Running/debugging" the application in the android studio. I use "nox" as an emulator. instead, adb.exe is installed

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

device not detected when "Running/debugging" the application in the android studio. I use "nox" as an emulator. instead, adb.exe is installed. 
yesterday I tried to find a solution it turned out I could, but I forgot to solve the problem, the point is I use "CMD" to reset/change "adb". but now I can't detect the device when running/debugging Android Studio.

Comment: It is a screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vPTpeFXkEw7FlF5PfIhbTUJR-qhDPAAz

Answer (score 0):

Us IP address of your emulator to connect 
        OR

Use YOUWAVE Emulator .... its fast and compatible with ANDROID STUDIO. .....

Comment: IT'S NOT WORKING

Comment: @RizkiIvaldi Use YOUWAVE EMULATOR

Comment: Or try reinstalling your PLATFORM TOOLS